# iOS Navigation Controller Background Glitch

Tags: ios, xcode, controller, navigation

OK, Ive looked everywhere for an answer, and I am unsure of what you may call this by a name - but I have detailed what my issue is below.

In my main.storyboard file, I have a view as a child from a navigation controller (i.e., allowing nav bar navigation) - being a MKMapView, which when you tap on a pin, it brings up the next scene.. This is all as it should be... (lets call it the "map" and the "detail" scene)

BUT!!!
When you hit the back button, the map view glitches and overlays the detail views background image over the mkmapview for about half a second. Would anyone be able to suggest what this problem is? Thanks soo much!

Due to stack overflow, I can't upload a picture just yet (reputation).. are you allowed to link externally?

Your help is very much appreciated.

EDIT: Ive uploaded a screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/e19gtx/8

Comment: yes you can link that externally

Comment: You might not be dismissing the views in the proper order and it corrupts the view. I've had a similar problem in which it was a call in the delegate method causing the problem before I dismissed one view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

in ViewDidLoad.

Basically make sure your glitchy view has a background colour.

Comment: Weird Huh? No change, My view is designed mostly in Storyboards and the view glitches out when you "back navigate" in where the detail view's backgroundImage (just a UIImage placed there via interface builder) gets squished on the screen as a "overlay". It only stays there for a half second.. Thanks though!

Comment: Weird, I have seen that happen on pushing a view controller with view background not set to a colour. Not sure about popping the view controller. But thought they may be related. You are definitely setting the background colour for both screens in your storyboard, right?

Comment: Ahah! Thanks! It appear that it ISN'T fully to do with the colour, as it seems that it makes no change, it does appear though that it has something to do with the "aspect fit" settings of the image... On one setting, it renders perfectly.. (Aspect Fill was probably rendering the background off the view)

Comment: Interesting. Can't really say more without looking at your code. If you can't get it working soon, a bit more details would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use segue? Try manually pusing the "detail" view controller onto the map using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:#yourDetailViewController# animated:YES]
```

hope this works, i encountered this before.